# interp2 matlab function equivalent in Java opencv

Tags: java, matlab, opencv, image-processing, interpolation

I was wondering if there is any function in opencv (Java) equivalent to the Matlab interp2 function. I am trying to resize the width of a given image. I investigated this matter and found that remap function could be of use but honestly I didn't understand the map1 and map2 parameters in this function:

```
remap(Mat src, Mat dst, Mat map1, Mat map2, int interpolation)
```

Furthermore here is my Matlab code:

```
IM=interp2(IM,linspace(1,size(IM,2),size(IM,2)*overSample),linspace(1,size(IM,1),size(IM,1))','nearest');
```

I implemented the linspace function based on the matlab script of this version.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to resize the image, why not use [`resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#resize(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Size,%20double,%20double,%20int))?

Comment: Hello , in fact the resize isnt the goal ( my goal is to eliminate some discontinuities in the image by oversampling which leads to a resize..)

Comment: So if you're not trying to resize your image, perhaps you could explain exactly what you're trying to do and how we can help you.